# Left outer Table Joins on multiple conditions.

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and want to left outer join.

First Table

```
Id    RenewalTerm   EffectiveDt RenewalDt
400001   -1         8/1/2012    8/1/2013
400001    0         8/1/2013    8/1/2014
400001    1         8/1/2014    8/1/2015
400001    2         8/1/2015    8/1/2016
400001    3         8/1/2016    8/1/2017
400001    4         8/1/2017    8/1/2018
```

SecondTable

```
Id    RenewalTerm   MaxSize AY      DateTime    EffectiveDt RenewalDt
400001  -1             2    2013    2/25/2013   8/1/2012    8/1/2013
400001  -1           1.75   2013    2/25/2013   8/1/2012    8/1/2013
400001   2           1.75   2016    5/1/2016    8/1/2015    8/1/2016
```

Expected Table
Result

```
 Id     RenewalTerm EffectiveDt RenewalDt   DateTime     AY     MaxSize
 400001 -1          8/1/2012    8/1/2013    *2/25/2013  2013    2*
*400001 -1          8/1/2012    8/1/2013    2/25/2013   2013    1.75*
 400001  0          8/1/2013    8/1/2014    NULL        NULL    NULL
 400001  1          8/1/2014    8/1/2015    NULL        NULL    NULL
*400001  2          8/1/2015    8/1/2016    5/1/2016    2016    1.75*
 400001  3          8/1/2016    8/1/2017    NULL        NULL    NULL
 400001  4          8/1/2017    8/1/2018    NULL        NULL    NULL
```

In second table, renewal term -1 is repeating and in first table theres just one -1. So, one of the -1 should get updated with Maxsize, AY and datetime and a new row of -1 from second table should be added to first table.

In second table, renewal term 2 is just once. So the extra columns Maxsize, AY and datetime from second table should get added to first.

I have been trying to solve this for a long time. Can somebody please help me with this. Thank you.

I have added italic/stars to show which data got updated/added

Comment: Could you share what have you tried so far? i.e. your sql query

Answer (score 0):

[Basic Left Join theory](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

[COALESCE function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT a.ID, a.RenewalTerm, COALESCE( b.EffectiveDt, a.EffectiveDt ) AS EffectiveDt,
    COALESCE( b.RenewalDt, a.RenewalDt ) AS RenewalDt,
    MaxSize, AY, [DateTime]
FROM [FristTable] AS a
    LEFT JOIN [SecondTable] AS b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.RenewalTerm = b.RenewalTerm
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple `left join` + `coalesce` resolve your problem.
Please check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dc934/3) fiddle:

```
Select 
  t1.Id,
  t1.RenewalTerm,
  coalesce(t2.EffectiveDt, t1.EffectiveDt) EffectiveDt,
  coalesce(t2.RenewalDt, t1.RenewalDt) RenewalDt,
  t2.DateTime,
  t2.AY,
  t2.MaxSize
From 
  table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.RenewalTerm = t2.RenewalTerm
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this as:

```
select t1.*, t2.DateTime, t2.AY, t2.MaxSize
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.renewalterm = t2.renewalterm;
```

Perhaps I'm missing something, but I see no need for `coalesce()`.